# JXG Graph Fill Cubes

Tags: javascript

I am trying to shade cubes in jxg graph based on a slider value but skip space in-between the cubes. I figured out how to do it for 3 cubes but need to propagate this for 60 small cubes.
https://jsfiddle.net/timpersson/kj1pqct5/

```
var b3 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox3', {boundingbox: [0, 30, 100, 0], axis: false, showNavigation:false, showCopyright:false});



c1 = 10;
r1 = 10;
s = 10;
xo=3;
yo=4;
xs = 15
sp = 5;

var v1_ = [],v2_ = [],v3_ = [],v4_ = [],v5_ = [], v6_ = [], v7_ = [],v8_ = [], v9_ = [], v10_, j1_ = [];
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
v1_[i] = b3.create('point', [i*xs+c1,r1],{visible:false});
v2_[i] = b3.create('point', [i*xs+c1+s,r1],{visible:false});
v3_[i] = b3.create('point', [i*xs+c1+s,r1+s],{visible:false});
v4_[i] = b3.create('point', [i*xs+c1,r1+s],{visible:false});
v5_[i] = b3.create('point', [i*xs+c1-xo,r1+yo],{visible:false});
v6_[i] = b3.create('point', [i*xs+c1+s-xo,r1+s+yo],{visible:false});
v7_[i] = b3.create('point', [i*xs+c1-xo,r1+s+yo],{visible:false});

j1_[i] = b3.create('polygon',[v1_[i],v2_[i],v3_[i],v4_[i],v7_[i],v6_[i],v3_[i],v4_[i],v1_[i],v5_[i],v7_[i],v5_[i]],{hasInnerPoints:false,highlightFillColor:'white', fillColor:'white'});
}

var v8, v9, v10,pg1,pg2;
s1 = b3.create('slider',[[10,5], [50,5],[0,0,30]]);
t = s1.Value();
s1.on('drag', function(){


if (t <= 10){
b3.removeObject([v8, v9, v10, pg1]);
t = s1.Value();
v8 = b3.create('point', [c1+t,v1_[0].Y()], {visible:false});
v9 = b3.create('point', [c1+t,v4_[0].Y()],{visible:false});
v10 = b3.create('point', [c1-xo+t,v7_[0].Y()],{visible:false});
pg1 = b3.create('polygon', [v1_[0],v8,v9,v10,v7_[0],v5_[0]]);
            }

 if (10 < t && t <= 20 ){

b3.removeObject([v8, v9, v10, pg1, pg2]);
pg1 = b3.create('polygon', [v1_[0],v2_[0],v3_[0],v6_[0],v7_[0],v5_[0]]);
t = s1.Value();
v8 = b3.create('point', [sp+c1+t,v1_[0].Y()],{visible:false});
v9 = b3.create('point', [sp+c1+t,v4_[0].Y()],{visible:false});
v10 = b3.create('point', [sp+c1-xo+t,v7_[0].Y()],{visible:false});
pg2 = b3.create('polygon', [v1_[1],v8,v9,v10,v7_[1],v5_[1]]);
                      }
  if (20 < t && t <= 30 ){

b3.removeObject([v8, v9, v10,pg1, pg2]);
pg1 = b3.create('polygon', [v1_[0],v2_[0],v3_[0],v6_[0],v7_[0],v5_[0]]);
pg2 = b3.create('polygon', [v1_[1],v2_[1],v3_[1],v6_[1],v7_[1],v5_[1]]);
t = s1.Value();
v8 = b3.create('point', [2*sp+c1+t,v1_[0].Y()],{visible:false});
v9 = b3.create('point', [2*sp+c1+t,v4_[0].Y()],{visible:false});
v10 = b3.create('point', [2*sp+c1-xo+t,v7_[0].Y()],{visible:false});
pg3 = b3.create('polygon', [v1_[2],v8,v9,v10,v7_[2],v5_[2]]);                      
                      }
}  
  );
```

Any idea how to put this in a for loop?